# Magento2: How to override menu.xml?

Tags: magento2, overrides, menu

I want to add a new custom menu above the **Views** in the custom module.

[image]

I am creating a custom report.

Can anyone please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this file in your custom module here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Magento_Reports::custom_report" title="Custom Report" translate="title" module="Magento_Reports" sortOrder="9" parent="Magento_Reports::report_products" action="reports/custom/url" resource="Magento_Reports::viewed"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Thank you. Already try this. but not working

Comment: Which magento version you're using?

Comment: I am using 2.3.3

Comment: Can you please add this in parent ? **Magento_Reports::report_statistics**

Comment: I think you've removed this **Magento_Reports::report_products** so it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to override menu.xml. Just add this below code in your menu.xml file :

```
<menu>
    <add id="Vendor_Module::section"  title="Section"  module="Vendor_Module" sortOrder="05" resource="Magento_Reports::viewed" action="module/index/index"  parent="Magento_Reports::report_products"/>    
</menu>
```

Hope, it will helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you. Already try this. but not working